# Moving Lego NXT's motor

Tags: ros, nxt, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been playing with ROS+Lego NXT and after successfully playing
with the sensors I got stuck trying to move one motor.

The only parameter I found on nxt_msgs related to that is
JointCommand, but JointCommand only has "effort".

So I tried:

rostopic pub /joint_command nxt_msgs/JointCommand '{name: 'motor', effort: 10}'

And confirmed that this value changed with:

rostopic echo joint_command

name: motor
effort: 10.0

But no movement. I also tried the nxt_teleop demo, but no matter the
arrow key I press, none of the motor move.

I also tried the steps described in this post, but had no success (http://answers.ros.org
/question/486/trouble-following-lego-nxt-tutorials)

Any ideas?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10874/moving-lego-nxt%27s-motor/) by [Rafael Aroca](https://answers.ros.org/users/943/rafael-aroca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-08-10**:
were you able to run the test on the installation page (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt/Installation)? or run the first tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Getting%20started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using the command rxgraph when your system is running to see what is subscribing and publishing in order to better diagnose the problem.

nxt_teleop should publish to cmd_vel which publishes to base_controller which publishes to joint_command

There are 2 tutorials online for Teleoperation, I found the nxt_teleop (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_teleop) works, and I have not had success with nxt_assisted_teleop.

So I run roscore, a robot.launch file (which reads robot.yaml for parameters), and then I launch teleop_keyboard.launch from the directory .../stacks/nxt_apps/nxt_teleop
and then use the arrow keys to drive the nxt.

---

Originally posted by [Jhatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/946/jhatch/) with karma: 16 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0